# Single phase neutral current & three-phase neutral current with respect to kirchhoff's law

Tags: circuit-analysis, three-phase, kirchhoffs-laws, load, single-phase

In the below schematic, would be the sum of all current in the single phase neutral wires equal to the current in neutral wire going to the 3 phase main disconnect?

In theory, we know that if the 3 phases are equal, neutral current is zero. How would this be still true if each single phase neutral current is not zero (some loads would be on)?

What is the consideration ofKirchhoff's law in this context?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvr3Vw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Original schematic.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f43DSX.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Schematic redrawn for OP to tidy up.*

Comment: You need to specify which of the 3 phases each of your loads is connected to before you can sum the neutral currents.

Comment: @brhans Are not the neutral wires all going to one node which is the neutral bus?

Comment: @brhans and in anyways, can you explain why would the neutral current be zero if all three phases are equal even though there is some current in each phase's neutral?

Comment: I've redrawn the schematic the way most engineers would understand it. I've assumed the loads are connected L1, L2, L3, L1, L2 as you didn't indicate where they were connected. You can edit to fix. You're looking for the current in AM1. I also removed all the bold text which looks like you're shouting at us. Use boldface for emphasis. If everything is emphasised then nothing is emphasised.

Comment: This is a very simple problem.... This is the typical unbalance three phase load problem. You have 2 load that are in parallel which give you 38 ohms and you have  1 load at 76 ohms. The current drawn will not be exactly 3 amps that is for sure. There will be homopolar current in this circuit.

Comment: @MathieuL How could the unbalanced current be equal to the sum of all single phase neutral currents (considering Kirchhoff's law)?

Comment: @Gold_Sky Because your current don't cancel in the neutral point, You have a Neutral current flowing meaning that Ia + Ib + Ic != 0. If the system is balance Ia+Ib+Ic = 0 = In